# Session state in SP 2013 foundation

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, deployment, solution-package

**Scenario:**

We have 4 WFEs with SharePoint installed on them, behind a Load balancer.

**Goal:**

Deploy wsps without downtime.

**Question:**

1. Can enable SQL Session state in SharePoint foundation 2013 ?
2. Is above scenario even possible with or without SQL Session state in SQL DB ?

Answer (score 1):

i think you can achieve zero downtime without it.As you have 4 WFE which are load balanced, make life easy. You can use the local parameter in the Install-SPSolution command which will install the locally on the server.

- Take WFE1 out of load balancer and run powershell to install the WSP locally. `Install-SPSolution "Sol name" –GACDeployment –Local`
- Once Solution will deployed on server locally(you can confirm it via Central admin), Put back the WFE1 into load balancer
- Now repeat the above steps for remaining WFEs

For the App servers, Please make sure for All services application have atleast 2 end points (services instances running on 2 different servers). Because when you run the install spsolution with local then it will cause outage for the endpoints on the local servers.

Comment: Thank you +1, I think network infra have problem with there load balancer, it's not draining out user sessions when they leave, which is why we are going to use Session state, even though I will consider your comments, could you also give some information on session state as well please e.g. can be enabled in SP Foundation for curiosity ? ta again